# Web App Hide address bar firing too late

Tags: jquery, url, hide, issue-tracking, address-bar

Having found how to hide the address bar from a post on SO, I need to execute this script in order to get the viewport height **AFTER the address bar is scrolled out of view**.

But the H and W vaues are returned BEFORE the scroll takes place, although I call the getViewPortSize() function 1 second later. Once the dilog box is clicked OK, the address bar is scrolled!

Anybody can help me getting this working as expected?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener("load", function () { if (!window.pageYOffset) { hideAddressBar(); } });
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", hideAddressBar);

        setTimeout(getViewPortSize(), 1000);

        function getViewPortSize() {
            var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
            var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

            alert('viewportHeight: ' + viewportHeight);
        }
        function hideAddressBar() {
            if (!window.location.hash) {
                if (document.height < window.outerHeight) {
                    document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
                }

                setTimeout(function () { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Of course, a hack would be to add 25px (Android) to the viewport height (and whatever height for iPhone) but that would just be err... a poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer:

Replaced setTimeout(getViewPortSize(), 1000);

With:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    getViewPortSize()
});
```

So that the function is not launched until the scroll happened.